# PhoneGap File Transfer API to Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, api, file-upload, cordova

Im trying to get an image with the use of the file transfer API found at:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

to an Mysql database. I can currently get it to a server without any problems however i cannot find any tutorials/code snippets on how you would get it to Mysql. I currently have the code below however it just returns "no image selected" each time.

If anyone has an advice, links etc id be very greatful.

```
// Create MySQL login values and 
// set them to your login information.
$username = "";
$password = "";
$host = "";
$database = "";

 // Make the connect to MySQL or die
 // and display an error.
   $link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select your database
mysql_select_db ($database); 

// Make sure the user actually 
// selected and uploaded a file
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

  // Temporary file name stored on the server
  $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

  // Read the file 
  $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
  $data = addslashes($data);
  fclose($fp);


  // Create the query and insert
  // into our database.
  $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images ";
  $query .= "(image) VALUES ('$data')";
  $results = mysql_query($query, $link);

  // Print results
  print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

}
else {
```

print "No image selected/uploaded";
    }

```
 // Close our MySQL Link
mysql_close($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that tutorial. It doesn't include MySQL but save the picture on your PHP server :

[Upload a File to a Remote Server with PhoneGap](http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/)

Answer (score 0):

1. addslashes() is deprecated, unreliable, and WILL cause you grief. Don't use it for database operations. That's why there's mysql_real_escape_string()
2. You have an invalid method of checking for a successful upload. The _FILES data will be populated with what you're checking for, but it's still populated with that even if the upload failed. You must check `$_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK` to ensure that an upload DID successfully occur.
3. There's no need for the fopen/fread/filesize stuff. A simple `file_get_contents()` will do that for you with less hassle.
4. You have no error checking on your database operations, and assume they've all succeeded. This is very bad. Even if your SQL statements are perfectly written, there's any number of OTHER reasons the query can fail. Particularly when you're inserting blobs - you don't check how large the file is, and blindly stuff it into a query - this can easily exceed MySQL's configured max_allowed_packet, killing the query. You MUST check for query failure with `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` as a bare mininum option.